# Image of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T : V \to W$ be a linear transformation. If $A$ is a subspace of $V$, show that its image,
>   $$
> T(A) = \left\{ T(x) \in W \mid x \in A \right\},
> $$
>   is a subspace of $W$.

I have no idea how to proceed with this question. Can someone give some pointers, please? Thanks

edit:

let vectors a1 and a2 belong to A, and vector x1 and x2 belongs to Im(T(A)) be the corresponding vectors of W to a1 and a2, and b belong to all real numbers. bx1 + x2 -> bT(a1) + T(a2) -> T(ba1 + a2). Since T is linear. Is this right??

Comment: You need to show that $T(A)$ has the zero vector ($0_W$) and is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication. This should be easy using the definition of a linear transformation.

Comment: thanks for the help, i think i got it?

Comment: That's basically it. A couple things you might want to clean up: 1) you should write $x_1,x_2\in T(A)$ instead of $x_1, x_2\in Im(T(A))$ (the latter is incorrect notation); 2) you should argue that since $x_1\in T(A)$ that $\exists a_1\in A$ s.t. $T(a_1)=x_1$ (and similarly for $x_2$); 3) you still need to show that $0_W$ is in $T(A)$ (use the linearity of $T$ and the fact that $0\cdot 0_W$). To elaborate on point 2), you currently assume $a_1$ and $a_2$ as arbitrary vectors rather than elements which map to $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $w_1,w_2 \in T(A)$ then $w_1 = T(a_1)$ and $w_2 = T(a_2)$, for some $a_1,a_2 \in A$. Thus $w_1+w_2 = T(a_1)+T(a_2) = T(a_1+a_2)$, so that $w_1 + w_2 \in T(A)$. Similarly, $w \in T(A)$ implies $kw \in T(A)$ for every scalar $k$. Then $T(A)$ is a subspace of $W$.